# Gmail Forward email to group, with recipients replying to specific person

Tags: gmail, email-forwarding

I forward a LOT of emails every day. Most of the time, people reply to who they need to.
Example. "Do you need money?" Email. Forward to people who need money. But I don't need them to reply to me, I need them to reply to Mr. Money.

I hope this makes sense. But if you click "reply" in the email you received from me, I get the reply. It would be nice to have it go to another specific email which changes with almost every forward. In Mozilla's version of email Thunderbird, you can set a specific reply to email address. But due to security, they don't allow Thunderbird used here.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible to mimic in Gmail itself. If you forwarded an email you've become a part of "Reply group" and it's up to Mr. Money to exclude you from a chain.